# "I go to school tomorrow" to imply that I will attend school tomorrow

Tags: verbs, future-tense, future-time

"I go to school tomorrow" to imply that I will attend school tomorrow. Is the aforementioned expression within inverted commas correct?

Comment: By the way, this `"` is a speech mark, and this `'` is an apostrophe or an inverted comma, depending on usage.

Comment: To 'go to school' means to 'regularly attend school as a pupil'. It _may_ be used inchoatively, at least in the UK ('Jimmy goes to school tomorrow'), but one wouldn't expect such command of the language from a 4-year-old.

Comment: Try this instead: **"Tomorrow I'm going to school."** Use the Present Continuous tense for actions that have been planned and/or prearranged in the past. PC tense is used to express actions in progress, and to express a future arrangement, usually a time reference is needed, e.g. "I'm meeting Alice for coffee on Saturday"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it correct to say "we start tomorrow"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/226650/is-it-correct-to-say-we-start-tomorrow)

Comment: Sorry about the migration to ELL. I voted to close this question as a duplicate to the one @Mari-LouA mentioned. However, because 3 people voted for migration and I was the 5th vote, the system sided with the votes for migration.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think we can use present simple when talking about a time tabled event, especially with "start". Am I right?

Comment: In American English, `"` is called a "quotation mark" and `'` is an apostrophe. We don't use the terms "inverted comma" or "speech mark" at all.

Comment: Cardinal, you are correct. Present simple can be used to talk about time-tabled events in the future, particularly when someone other than the person we are talking about has set the schedule. "The president is set to give a speech next Monday", " The new policy goes into effect next month." (my own examples)

Answer (score 1):

It is not ungrammatical. There are even situations when it would be natural. However, as we don't have any more context it's hard to say whether it's right for you.

Present simple, like "*I go*", can mean something that's happening now - but it's also used for statements of general truth, or about things that are habitual. "I go to school", on its own, isn't usually used to mean you are in the process of getting to school - it means that you attend school *in general*. You are a schoolkid (or a student, if you're using the American usages of *school* to include college and university).

Thus, "I **go to** school tomorrow" can be a perfectly good statement of general truth. However, depending on context you might want to say "I **will** go to school tomorrow", or "I **can** go to school tomorrow", or "I **should** go to school tomorrow". It might even be better to have a different verb, like "I **start** school tomorrow". It all depends on context and exactly what you're trying to say.